# Surplomber par / de par / de sa beauté

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Alors que le chemin aboutit à la vallée et nous tournons à droite, un
> temple des gardiens émerge du brouillard, nous surplombant **par** sa
> beauté.
>
> Alors que le chemin aboutit à la vallée et nous tournons à droite, un
> temple des gardiens émerge du brouillard, nous surplombant **de par** sa
> beauté.
>
> Alors que le chemin aboutit à la vallée et nous tournons à droite, un
> temple des gardiens émerge du brouillard, nous surplombant **de** sa
> beauté.

Est-ce que "par", "de par" et "de" sont possibles après "surplomber" ? Je ne trouve aucune préposition, mis à part "sur", dans mes dictionnaires.

Comment: En générale, une chose surplombe une autre. Mais on n'est pas surplombé "par la beauté." Le beau jardin nous surplombait....

Answer (score 1):

***Nous surplombant de sa beauté*** est pour moi le meilleur choix.

Il s'agit d'un effet de style car le fait que le temple nous surplombe et le fait qu'il soit beau ne sont pas liés. Au sens propre, on pourrait dire d'une part *le temple nous surplombe de sa hauteur, nous surplombe de 25 mètres, nous surplombe de sa tour, etc.* et d'autre part *le temple nous éblouit par sa beauté, nous enchante par sa beauté, etc.* Il y a une sorte d'ellipse qui réduit la phrase aux deux informations que l'on souhaite transmettre, le temple est au dessus de nous et il est très beau.

En revanche, ***un** temple **des** gardiens* n'est pas très heureux.

Comment: Pourquoi _un temple des gardiens_ n'est pas naturel ? Je peux effacer _des gardiens_, mais en russe cette expression est tout à fait normale. Enfin... peut-être que non. _Un temple de la Vérité_ sonne beaucoup mieux en russe.

Comment: Ce qui est naturel: *le temple des gardiens*, mais ça ne va pas ici ou *un temple de la guilde des gardiens*, *un temple de la confrérie des gardiens*, *un temple de la corporation des gardiens*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> nous surplombant de toute sa beauté

J’aurais aussi corrigé :

> et **que** nous tournons à droite

Et peut-être :

> nous submergeant par sa beauté